# How to test android app for ipv6 compatibility

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an existing android app, I'm on IPv4, how can I fake IPv6 address to test the application compatibility with it? or is there a better way to test IPv6 compatibility?

Comment: Please provide more details of what your app does. Normally, apps do not need to directly deal with IP address, so do not need to tested for IPv4 and IPv6. This is part of the separation of concerns provided by the OSI layers. Handling of IPv4/6 is done by the android OS. Please add more details if your app specifically need to deal with IP addresses.

Comment: The mobile cellular network of some Android phones has the APN setting enabled. You can specify the APN setting to ipv6  or ipv4/ipv6. On my Android device, can directly enable ipv6  or ipv4/ipv6, and then you can use the packet capture tool to connect to the server and query the network request by the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

A majority of apps will not require any changes as IPv6 is already supported by Android. However, if your app utilizes IPv4-specific APIs or hardcoded IP addresses, you'll need to make changes.

The easiest way to test your app for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 compatibility—which is the type of network most cellular carriers are deploying—is to set up a local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 network with your Pc or Mac. You can then connect to this network from your other devices for testing purposes.

[image: diagram]

Comment: I can't find any information how to setup DNS64/NAT64 network under Windows. Could please give some info?